# Как из переменной string отсоединить числа и записать их в переменную int?

Tags: c++

Есть переменная

```
string icq = "5123.1234.131.89";
```

Цифры могут быть любые.
Как мне отсоединить числа и поделить их на 4 части?

Чтобы было так
(1 часть).(2 часть).(3 часть).(4 часть).

Comment: И записать числа в переменную int
ЧТобы получилось 4 переменных содержащих в себе числа от переменной string, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: что должно быть на выходе? В одну переменную int нельзя записать четыре числа

Comment: Нужно из строки  "5123.1234.131.89"
Отсортировать числа. На выходе должно получится 4 переменных.
на пример
int a = 5123; (1 часть)

И так далее

Comment: способов много. По простому можете хранить индексы  символов  для которых  std::isdigit вернет false, и по ним разделять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего и без защиты от дурака —

```
string icq = "5123.1234.131.89";

int o[4];
char c;

istringstream ss(icq);
ss >> o[0] >> c >> o[1] >> c >> o[2] >> c >> o[3];

cout << o[0] << " - " << o[1] << " - " << o[2] << " - " << o[3];
```

Можно также использовать [`views::split`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view) из C++20.

P.S. Только вот на IP это как-то не тянет :) — октеты там до 255...

Comment: Не работает, выдаёт ошибку,
недопустимый полный тип,
отсутствует оператор >>, соответствующий этим операндам

Comment: @Overloads Видимо какой-то хедер забыли, или код скопировали неправильно.

Comment: @Overloads,  добавьте #include <sstream>
using std::istringstream;

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{ 
    string icq = "5123.1234.131.89";
    vector<string> snums(count(icq.begin(), icq.end(), '.') + 1);
    vector<int> nums(count(icq.begin(), icq.end(), '.') + 1);

    int cur_pos = 0;

    while (icq.size() != 0) {
        auto first_dot = icq.find_first_of('.');
        if (first_dot == string::npos)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < icq.size(); i++)
            {
                snums[cur_pos] += icq[i];
            }
            break;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < first_dot; i++)
        {
            snums[cur_pos] += icq[i];
        }
        cur_pos++;
        icq.erase(0, first_dot + 1);
    }


    for (size_t i = 0; i < snums.size(); i++)
    {
        nums[i] = stoi(snums[i]);
    }

    for (auto i : nums)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
   
}
```

Ход мыслей: создаём вектор будущих чисел и вспомогательный вектор строк, который мы сконвертируем в числовой вектор. Дальше разбиваем строку icq на числа и записываем их в вектор